# Where is the best place to store a user token in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, security, vuex, vuejs3

I'm building a VueJS client application where after the user logsin, the API is return a token. I'm using Vuex, but as far as I understand the response is stored in state in memory only. In almost every example I see data like a token is written to localStorage which creates a security risk.
What is the best way  to persist the token after login (not localStorage nor cookies)?
example are appreciated

Comment: there is a reason it is stored in local storage as it is easy to manage over there. Also, only with token you cannot get data from any api. Also you can use Redux Store to save your token but only if you know how to manage that properly.

Comment: There are always security risks when you deal with client side. The mention of LS as security risk is a hearsay and lacks the context. Which is that a culprit is able to evaluate arbitrary JS code in user's browser, meaning that you or a user are potentially deep in trouble already. You're limited to what browser API provides, i.e. cookies and LS. IndexedDB doesn't really differ in this regard because if a culprit has to `window`, any browser API can be called. There are scenarios when cookies provide additional security measures, specifically `SameSite` and `HttpOnly`.

Comment: Basically all options are mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage and https://auth0.com/blog/secure-browser-storage-the-facts/ . Another option is to keep auth layer in service or web worker. It's not persistent but survives page reloads. I'm voting to close as this isn't a proper question for SO. There are no "best" places, only suitable.

Comment: If you want to avoid login every time when the user does browser refresh. Then storing somewhere in the client seems to be the option to choose. The strategy is to store a ticket/token that is time-limited. And the process by how the valid ticket is stored should be as secure as possible.

For static websites, the PKCE flow seems most secure (to my knowledge). example here https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce